# SlideToggle first and last div toggle ones in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, toggle, slidetoggle

I have been using jquery to create some tabs. Here is my basic code.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymww367t/)

I want to set it so the initial opening of the tab content is a slideToggle but then moving between tabs is a standard toggle then when the user clicks the item to close the items I want it to slideToggle again. So for instance.

Open Tab 1 - SlideToggle, move to Tab 2 - Toggle, move to Tab 3 - Toggle, move to Tab 2 - Toggle, close tab 2 - slideToggle

Is this possible and if so how can I achieve this. I have tried to google this but I can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks in advance for any help.

HTML

```
<div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
<div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
<div class="tab">Tab 3</div>

<div class="lrgWork"> Tab Content 1</div>
<div class="lrgWork"> Tab Content 2</div>
<div class="lrgWork"> Tab Content 3</div>
```

JS

```
    $('.tab').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('.lrgWork').eq(index).slideToggle().siblings('.lrgWork').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
var currentTabOpen=0;//keeps track of what tab is open
var tabOpen=false;//keeps track of whether a tab is opened
$('.tab').click(function() {
    var index=$(this).index();
    if(currentTabOpen==index||!tabOpen){//if we're either closing a tab, or opening one,
        $('.lrgWork').eq(index).slideToggle();//use the slide animation
        tabOpen=!tabOpen;//and now the tab is open if it was closed and vice versa
    }
    currentTabOpen=index;//make sure we're keeping track of the opened tab
    $('.lrgWork').eq(index).show().siblings('.lrgWork').hide();//don't use the animation
});
```

and see here the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txpftffh/3/).